# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent NodeJS LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.JS API

```
router.get('/signInLinkedIn', function(req, res, next) {
    Linkedin.setCallback('http://localhost:5000')
    var results = Linkedin.auth.authorize(res);
    res.write({response:results});
});
```

I would like to send the results back to the frontend but I got the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

How can I fix it OR is there any workaround so that it send the response back to the frontend ?

Comment: This error comes when the response has already sent to the client and you are trying to send it again.

Answer (score 0):

So the workaround for this is `var results = Linkedin.auth.authorize();`. Remove `res`